# Django select foreign key with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problem with this: I want to create a modal to pick up the related object from the foreign key. The modal shows up, render the form and list the results. The search button close the modal and I don't know how to pick up the object with the radiobox. My code below:

**pay_form.html**

```
<div class="form-inline">
 <label for="idticket" style="margin-right: 5px">Ticket:</label>
    {{ payForm.idticket }}
     <a data-toggle="modal" href="searchTicket" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
      <i class="icon-search"></i> 
     </a>
</div>
<a href="/payments/cash" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
</form>
 <div id="searchTicket" class="modal fade" style="display: none">
       {% include "payments/ticket_search.html" %}
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**search_ticket.html**

```
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Selecct Ticket</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">

<form action="" method="get"/>
 <fieldset>
<div class="form-inline">
    <label>Ticket:</label>
    <input type="text" name="idticket"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Search"/>
 </fieldset>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>TICKET</th>
    <th>DATE</th>
    <th>AMOUNT</th>
</tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
{% for result in results %}
    <tr>
    <th><input type="radio" value="{{result.ticket}}"></th>
    <th>{{result.idticket}}</th>
    <th>{{result.date}}</th>
    <th>{{result.amount}}</th>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
 </tbody>
</table>
 </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Selecct</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

**views.py**

```
def ticket_search(request):
 if request.method == 'GET' and 'idticket' in request.GET:
    sForm = SearchTicketForm(request.GET)
    if sForm.is_valid():
        idticketF = sForm.cleaned_data.get('idticket')
        qs = Ticket.objects.all()
        if idticketF is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(idticket__icontains=idticketF)
        qs = qs.order_by('idticket',)
    else:
        qs = Ticket.objects.all().order_by('idticket',)        
 else:
    sForm = SearchTicketForm()
    qs = Ticket.objects.all().order_by('idticket',)
 return render(request, 'payments/ticket_search.html', {'sForm':sForm,'results':qs})
```

So theres two things: 
1) Perform the search into the modal window. 
2) Return the selected value.